# Error inflating class android.widget.Button with custom selector

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

I am trying to style a button in an android view, but since adding a custom selector I get the following error, what is causing this?:

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.Button

**View causing grief**

```
<Button
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/primary_button_style"
    android:textColor="@color/button_primary"
    android:background="@color/button_primary" />
```

**res/color/button_primary.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:color="@color/accent"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    />
  <item
    android:color="@color/grey"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    />
</selector>
```

**res/values/Styles.xml**

```
  <style name="primary_button_style" parent="android:Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">50px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">50px</item>
    <item name="android:height">50px</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">50px</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">50px</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30px</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  </style>
```

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio

Comment: put selector in drawable folder and add it like `android:background="@drawable/button_primary"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the selector you posted is fine for the text color, not for the background. You should add one in the folder `drawable/` and use `android:drawable` instead of `android:color`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:drawable="@color/accent"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    />
  <item
    android:drawable="@color/grey"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    />
</selector>
```

btw. if you use the same colors for the background and for the text you will not be able to see the latter

Comment: My button has different colour text and background on `android:state_enabled="false"` & `="true"`. Should I be using a separate selector file for the background (using your example), and the text colour (using my existing file)?

Comment: yes you have to. Mine was just an example based on what you posted. Replace the color with the "real" ones

Comment: Brilliant thanks, I was intending to extend the single selector I posted for both the text colour and background. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 3):

Call **`drawable instead of color`**

**You are getting**

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.Button

Problem is here

```
 android:background="@color/button_primary"
```

You can create `drawable`  folder and call

```
android:background="@drawable/button_primary"
```